# dynamically arrange catalog cards with angular and flex

Tags: angular, catalog, angular-flex-layout

I got a card component, and a card "deck" component of sorts.
I am getting the data from an external source then I am filling the deck cards and showing them on the screen.

The problem is that at the moment I am showing them 1 per row while I actually want to have ~3 cards per row and probably being able to reduce it to 2 and 1 when the screen gets smaller.

I tried tweaking it around and following some examples but I am missing something in my understanding.
At the moment I returned it back to its 'normal' look ( 1 per row ).
I believe I need to use `slice` in the `*ngFor` section of the data in some way but I failed to do so in a pleasing visual way.

Here is a link to a sample simplified app with a similar situation - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjkv2y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] on stackblitz so that we can see it in action and see what's wrong ?

Comment: Sure, I  will do that now.

Comment: why don't you use boostrap?

Comment: Ironically once I made a simplified example to show in the question I was able to isolate my issues and by following another sample code https://plnkr.co/edit/egsNB7TLOI1HHzBgbTbP?p=preview solve them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="padding: 16px 16px 16px 8px" fxLayout="row wrap">
        <div class="fixedContentSize"  *ngFor="let bpmn of bpmns">
            <app-card *ngIf=bpmn class="padding-bottom__16" [title]=bpmn.id [details]=bpmn.info></app-card> 
        </div>
</div>
```

`fxLayout="row wrap"` should be on conatiner element.

I have tested with below using css it worked

```
<div style="padding: 16px 16px 16px 8px" fxLayout="row wrap" style="display: flex; ">
        <div class="fixedContentSize"  *ngFor="let bpmn of bpmns">
            <app-card *ngIf=bpmn class="padding-bottom__16" [title]=bpmn.id [details]=bpmn.info></app-card> 
        </div>
</div>
```